# extending ienumerable method C#

Tags: c#

I wrote skip last method. When I call it with int array, I expect to only get 2 elements back, not 4.

What is wrong?

Thanks

```
public static class myclass
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
    {
        return source.Reverse().Skip(n).Reverse();
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] a = new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8};
        ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();

        a.SkipLast(2);
        for( int i = 0; i <a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(a[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the `ArrayList` for? Its not used here, thats a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to call as

```
var newlist = a.SkipLast(2);
for( int i = 0; i <newlist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(newlist[i]);
}
```

your method returning skipped list, but your original list will not update

if you want to assign or update same list you can set the returned list back to original as `a = a.SkipLast(2).ToArray();`

Comment: You should add `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing `newList` within that `for` loop?

Answer (score 3):

You should *assign the result*, not just put `a.SkipLast(2)`:

```
  a = a.SkipLast(2).ToArray(); // <- if you want to change "a" and loop on a 

  for( int i = 0; i <a.Length; i++) { ...
```

When you do `a.SkipLast(2)` it creates `IEnumerable<int>` and then *discards* it;
The most readable solution, IMHO, is to use *foreach* which is very convenient with LINQ:

```
  ...
  int [] a = new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8};

  foreach(int item in a.SkipLast(2)) 
    Console.Write(item);
```

Comment: what if i don't want to call it with anything other int array.

Comment: @user1048791: use "foreach"; I've written "a = a.SkipLast(2).ToArray();" just in order to keep your "for" loop intact. Usual way is to put "foreach" loops when working with LINQ - see my suggestion in the asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to,

```
foreach (var r in a.SkipLast(2))
{
    Console.Write(r);
}
```

for three reasons,

1. The `SkipLast` function returns the mutated sequence, it doesn't change it directly.
2. What is the point of using an indexer with `IEnumerable`? It imposes a needless count.
3. This code is easy to read, easier to type and shows intent.

---

For a more efficient generic `SkipLast` see [Matthew's buffer with enumerator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110126/659190)

---

Your example could use a more specialised `SkipLast`,

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IList<T> source, int n = 1)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (source.Count - n); i++)
    {
        yield return source[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other replies have answered your question, but wouldn't a more efficient implementation be this (which doesn't involve making two copies of the array in order to reverse it twice). It does iterate the collection twice (or rather, once and then count-n accesses) though:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    n = source.Count() - n;
    return source.TakeWhile(_ => n-- > 0);
}
```

Actually, if `source` is a type that implements `Count` without iteration (such as an array or a List) this will only access the elements `count-n` times, so it will be extremely efficient for those types.

Here is a better solution that only iterates the sequence once. It's data requirements are such that it only needs a buffer with `n` elements, which makes it very efficient if `n` is small compared with the size of the sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    T[] buffer = new T[n];

    var iter = source.GetEnumerator();

    while (iter.MoveNext())
    {
        if (count >= n)
            yield return buffer[count%n];

        buffer[count++%n] = iter.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is, an `IEnumerable` needn't garauntee that it can be enumerated twice. With the specific example given you'd be fine, arrays can obviously be enumerated multiple times but this is not true of every implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Jodrell That's true, but such enumerables always require special handling. You wouldn't want to use this with `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` for example. :)

Comment: Like in a generic extension. Another extention to IList<T> makes sense, then the count comes ready served.

Comment: Along these lines, with .NET 4.5 (VS2012), you can also do `public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
      {
        var arr = source.ToArray();
        return new ArraySegment<T>(arr, 0, Math.Max(0, arr.Length - n));
      }`- However your answer and this comment are not really answers to what the poster asked.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, as I said above, the other replies are the answers. This reply is merely a comment, but clearly I can't write formatted code in a normal comment! My answer is trying to avoid making copies of potentially large data, so doing `source.ToArray()` as you suggested is something I explicitly wanted to avoid!

Comment: By the way I like your latest addition, with the `n`-length buffer!

Comment: @Jodrell My other suggestion avoids the issues you raised.